# Legal responsibility of public posts

Tags: legal, open-graph-protocol

Given a public site with no logins: I let people post links to public Facebook profiles, and my site fetches the profile picture and displays it.

Would it be ok if I just told people to post profiles of which they had the owner’s permission?

Does such a statement exonerate me from copyright infringements and place the burden on the user?

**Edit:** For bonus points. Can the statement just be a notice under the button (that will save the link) that says that "By clicking this button you agree to the terms and conditions" with maybe a link to the terms and conditions.

Comment: > If I let people post links to public fb profiles.
What you mean by that?

Comment: @Deyan well would include a link to your profile ans if it is public we will extract public info from you profile.

Comment: @Murdock: I tried to clarify the wording of your question (and I added the OGP tag, as I’m assuming that your site uses this metadata to fetch the image). Please check if my edit is in your intention.

Comment: @unor Yes exactly. I've edited it again just to make one addition

Answer (score 1):

While it would be a good idea to include or add such a warning on a website, it would not exonerate you - the website owner or webmaster - from copyright infringement or place the burden on the user.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

If I am correct, posting links to a profile on facebook is not going to harm anything. Also, on the side of Facebook, when you upload photos, post updates, give information to facebook, they are now the owners of that data. (This information comes from reading the Terms of Service)

If people want their photos and information to be truly private, then they can "block" all access to their profile to becoming public. Plus a side note, the goal of social networking is to be free and share information with the world, not to have it private.